# Date Difference between two row second and last row

Tags: r

I try to calculate the date difference between second row and last row per group id.  The data looks like

```r
data<- data.frame(pid= c(1, 1, 1,1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3,3 ,3), day = c("25/07/2018", "19/10/2018", "17/01/2019", "19/03/2019", "10/09/2018","29/11/2018", "26/03/2019", "17/06/2016", "25/04/2018", "17/07/2018","05/04/2019", "09/02/2021"), catt=c(1,1,2,1,1,1,2,2,2,1,1,2))
```

data

|  | pid | day |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 25/07/2018 |
| 2 | 1 | 19/10/2018 |
| 3 | 1 | 17/01/2019 |
| 4 | 1 | 19/03/2019 |
| 5 | 2 | 10/09/2018 |
| 6 | 2 | 29/11/2018 |
| 7 | 2 | 26/03/2019 |
| 8 | 3 | 17/06/2016 |
| 9 | 3 | 25/04/2018 |
| 10 | 3 | 17/07/2018 |
| 11 | 3 | 05/04/2019 |
| 12 | 3 | 09/02/2021 |

I use the following code to obtain a difference in months.

```r
difftime("19/10/2018","19/03/2019 ", units = "days")/ (30)
difftime("29/11/2018","26/03/2019 ", units = "days")/ (30)
difftime("25/04/2018","09/02/2021 ", units = "days")/ (30)
```

The desired output
id     day              difference
1    25/07/2018
1    19/10/2018
1    17/01/2019
1    19/03/2019        7.13
2   10/09/2018
2   29/11/2018
2   26/03/2019       44.7
3   17/06/2016
3   25/04/2018
3   17/07/2018
3   05/04/2019
3   09/02/2021        196.7667

But it is difficult to large data, so anyone can help using lubricate () + slice() functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert to date object and calculate the difference between last and second date for each `pid`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

data %>%
  mutate(day = dmy(day)) %>%
  arrange(pid, day) %>%
  group_by(pid) %>%
  summarise(difference = (last(day) - day[2])/30)

#   pid difference
#  <dbl>      <dbl>
#1     1       5.03
#2     2       3.9 
#3     3      34.0
```

If you want to maintain the number of rows in the dataframe, use `mutate` and replace the `difference` only on the last row of the dataframe.

```
data %>%
  mutate(day = dmy(day)) %>%
  arrange(pid, day) %>%
  group_by(pid) %>%
  mutate(difference = ifelse(row_number() == n(), (last(day) - day[2])/30, NA))
```

---

Note that output from `difftime` in the question is incorrect.

```
#Wrong output
difftime("19/10/2018","19/03/2019 ", units = "days")
#Time difference of 214 days

#Correct output
difftime(dmy("19/03/2019"), dmy("19/10/2018"), units = "days")
#Time difference of 151 days
```